# Apache Location Reverseproxy URL not working

Tags: regex, apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to match a URL with multiple params and use reverse proxy to load some other content, for some reason the `Location Tag` isn't working.

Following is my `httpd.conf` file

```
<Location "/tracker/">
  ProxyPass "http://website.com:8290/track.js"
  ProxyPassReverse "http://website.com:8290/track.js"
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>

<Location "/tracker/csc-event?p=([^\s]+)&s=([^\s]+)&v=([^\s]+)&e=([^\s]+)&c=([^\s]+)&n=([^\s]+)&f=([^\s]+)&l=([^\s]+)&i=([^\s]+)&j=([^\s]+)&k=([^\s]+)&w=([^\s]+)&h=([^\s]+)&t=([^\s]+)&x=([^\s]+)">
  ProxyPass "http://website.com:8290/csc-event?p=([^\s]+)&s=([^\s]+)&v=([^\s]+)&e=([^\s]+)&c=([^\s]+)&n=([^\s]+)&f=([^\s]+)&l=([^\s]+)&i=([^\s]+)&j=([^\s]+)&k=([^\s]+)&w=([^\s]+)&h=([^\s]+)&t=([^\s]+)&x=([^\s]+)"
  ProxyPassReverse "http://website.com:8290/csc-event?p=([^\s]+)&s=([^\s]+)&v=([^\s]+)&e=([^\s]+)&c=([^\s]+)&n=([^\s]+)&f=([^\s]+)&l=([^\s]+)&i=([^\s]+)&j=([^\s]+)&k=([^\s]+)&w=([^\s]+)&h=([^\s]+)&t=([^\s]+)&x=([^\s]+)"
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

When I hit: `https://website.com/tracker` it works fine
But not with the other location, for eg If I hit:

```
https://website.com/tracker/csc-event?p=0%3Ajodv6q8w%3AdO9XGf6T4SCq7kz49hEEUwNvmkqR8Wxw&s=0%3Ajodv6q8w%3AHgkFFmKSZqdBB6E2C~F8xBKTHv8CGwbl&v=0%3AJ1gADq10d3pj1JL1lh4Dd7ZlLxQyl2~_&e=0%3AJ1gADq10d3pj1JL1lh4Dd7ZlLxQyl2~_0&c=jodvqubo&n=f&f=f&l=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2F&i=11y&j=k8&k=1&w=mj&h=i9&t=pageView&x=-e1v043
```

It shows `page not found error`. What am I doing wrong? Is there some problem with regex or some other config problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex in a location directive you should add a tilde (~), but even then Location does not match the query string. Add /tracker/csc-event as a Location and check the query string inside that directive.

Also, proxypass preverses the query string, no need to add it.